# xgboost multinomial classification error: "label and prediction size not match"

Tags: r, xgboost

Forward that I'm fairly new to both xgboost and R.

I am using xgboost in R to perform a multinomial classification on my data `dtrain`. The label I am using has six levels, so my code looks like this:

```
param1 <- list(objective = "multi:softprob"
          , num_class = 6
          , booster = "gbtree"  
          , eta = 0.5
          , max.depth = 7
          , min_child_weight = 10
          , max_delta_step = 5
          , subsample = 0.8
          , colsample_bytree = 0.8
          , lambda  = 3 # L2
          , alpha = 5 # L1
)
set.seed(2016)    
xgbcv1 <- xgb.cv(params = param1, data = dtrain, nround = 3000, nfold = 3,
             metrics = list("error", "auc"), maximize = T, 
             print_every_n = 10, early_stopping_rounds = 10)
```

This throws me the following error:

```
Error in xgb.iter.update(fd$bst, fd$dtrain, iteration - 1, obj) : 
amalgamation/../src/objective/multiclass_obj.cc:75: Check failed: 
label_error >= 0 && label_error < nclass SoftmaxMultiClassObj: label must be in [0, num_class), num_class=6 but found 6 in label.
```

So I tried setting `num_class = 7`, which throws this error:

```
Error in xgb.iter.eval(fd$bst, fd$watchlist, iteration - 1, feval) : 
amalgamation/../src/metric/elementwise_metric.cc:28: Check failed: 
(preds.size()) == (info.labels.size()) label and prediction size not match, hint: use merror or mlogloss for multi-class classification
```

What's going on here? Does `num_class` need to be greater than `label_error` or equal to it?

Comment: pls use `dput()`to share your data,...

Comment: Did you overcome it in the end? I found a solution over which worked for me. Specifically for my y variable, `set y <- y - 1` (I ddn't see a target variable in your call to xgb) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36086529/understanding-num-classes-for-xgboost-in-r

Answer (score 2):

The XGboost algorithm requires that class labels start from 0 and increase sequentially to the maximum number of classes.
This is a bit of an inconvenience as you need to keep track of what Class name goes with which label.

Convert your Class target variable to numeric and subtract it with 1.

```
df$class_numeric<-as.numeric(df$class_target)
df<-df%>%mutate(class_numeric=class_numeric-1)
```

Comment: Key point here! no negative classes, just spent a few hours looking for the issue with classes labelled -1,0,1

Answer (score -1):

if number of levels in the dependent variable is 6 then give num_class = 7. Meaning specify num_class = levels(Dependent Variable) + 1

Answer (score -1):

try :

```
set metrics = list("mlogloss")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks